# I am trying to get my navbar how I want it to be though I am having some issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix my code on a project from freecodecamp. I am a newbie and I am having some issues with it.

My Header "JS documentation" seems to be acting like it has a position: absolute on it but it doesn't and it seems to scroll with the rest of the body though I cannot see why that is happening. Even though it and the ul is wrapped in the navbar only the header seems to be affected by any changesImake to the specific navbar selector  and I cannot understand why. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

This is what it is supposed to look like

https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/NdrKKL

Codepen HTML for that portion

Code pen Html

```
<nav id="navbar">
  <header>JS Documentation</header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#What_you_should_already_know"
        >What you should already know</a
      >
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#JavaScript_and_Java">JavaScript and Java</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Hello_world">Hello world</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Variables">Variables</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#Declaring_variables">Declaring variables</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Variable_scope">Variable scope</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Global_variables">Global variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Constants">Constants</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Data_types">Data types</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#if...else_statement">if...else statement</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#while_statement">while statement</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#Function_declarations"
        >Function declarations</a
      >
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Reference">Reference</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Codepen Css

```
    #navbar {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 290px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 22, 22, 0.4);
}

header {
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: thin;
}

#main-doc header {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

and this is my actual code where I have the issues

I will only be posting a portion of the code as it would be very long imo here

https://codepen.io/RomarioR/pen/zYqpjxZ

My HTML

```
<nav id="navbar">
        <header >
          <h1 class="first.header">JS Documentation  </h1>   
        </header>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#what_you_should_already_know"class="nav-link">What you should already know</a></li>
            <li><a href="#javascript_and_java" class="nav-link">Javascript and Java</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hello_world" class="nav-link"> Hello World</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#variables" class="nav-link">Variables</a></li>
              <li><a href="#declaring_variables" class="nav-link">Declaring Variables</a></li>
            <li><a href="#variable_scope" class="nav-link">Variable Scope</a></li>
              <li><a href="#global_variables" class="nav-link">Global Variables</a></li>
              <li><a href="#constants" class="nav-link">Constants</a></li>
            <li><a href="#data_types" class="nav-link">Data Types</a></li>
            <li><a href="#if_else_statement" class="nav-link">if...else statement</a></li>
              <li><a href="#while_statement" class="nav-link">while Statement</a></li>
              <li><a href="#function_declarations" class="nav-link">Function Declarations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#reference" class="nav-link">Reference</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

My Css

```
    .first-header{
  margin: 0;  
  font-size:1.8em; 
}

header h1{
   font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 20%;
 
  
} 

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color:#707175; 
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  border-right: solid;
  height: 100%;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Although it requires some other changes, #navbar should be positioned fixed, not relative. `#navbar{position: fixed;}`

Comment: Yes thanks I had a #navbar selector and a #nvbar ul selector with position: fixed I was trying things when I added that relative thanks. When I do anything for the navbar selector it only affects the header though the ul is in it. Here is my code again https://codepen.io/RomarioR/pen/zYqpjxZ